# Can I use the ENet library in a commercial game?

Tags: licensing, commercial

I have some problems understanding [ENet's license](http://enet.bespin.org/License.html). It's not [the zlib license](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_license.html) as far as I know, but it seems like it's not [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) either. I'm not a native English speaker and I can't understand what the license exactly is.

Can I use ENet for a commercial game? If yes, do I need to mention that I used ENet *and* do I need to deliver ENet's license with my game?

I have no problem with mentioning that I use ENet in my credits, but ENet's license delivering thing seems just stupid and not-understable to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [MIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) license. You can do anything with MIT licensed software as long as you include its license somewhere in the distribution (it gives credit and disclaims warranty for the MIT licensed part). So commercial software is ok, and your product can be closed-source if you want (so you are *not* forced to use MIT license for your own product).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I just need to put enet's license for example in credits, and my game doesn't have to be under the MIT license and can be commercial product? Also big thanks for quick answer!

Comment: That is correct (just write something like "This software uses ENet library, which license is as follows:", so that people don't mistakenly think that you are licensing the whole package as MIT).

Comment: Great! Thanks again, you helped me a lot and very quickly :) I'll just put that text in credits.

Comment: @Bartek Please accept the answer if it satisfies you by clicking the check mark below the score.

Comment: Done, sorry for doing it so late but I wasn't home. Thanks again.